# Squished armature after deleting animation

Tags: animation, rigging

I am having a problem where my aramture seems scaled down on the y axis after deleting an animation action. Has anyone experienced this and know how too fix it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

probably you deleted the animation in a frame where the scale value of some bones was not equal 1.0. Go to pose mode, select all bones and press alt-s, alt-g, and alt-r to reset scale, position and rotation of all bones.